# Laravel get request post array

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Im using Laravel 5 and Im trying to get a value from my posted form.
This works fine for normal form input names, like:

```
$request->input('stripeToken')
```

However if the input name is a array like `name="order['amount']"`then I cant get the value. I've tried with:

```
$request->input( "order['return_url']" )
```

Anyone got any tips for this?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use dot notation:

```php
$value = $request->input('order.return_url');
```

Answer (score 12):

omit the quotes into the array brackets

```
<input name="order[amount]">
<input name="order[amount2]">
```

then you can get the value for example

```
return $request->input('order')['amount'];
return $request->input('order')['amount2'];
```

or

```
return $request->get('order')['amount'];
return $request->get('order')['amount2'];
```

Comment: Thanks, your response helped me a lot!

Answer (score 2):

**[Retrieving A Portion Of The Input Data](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/requests)**
If you need to retrieve a sub-set of the input data, you may use the only and except methods. Both of these methods will accept a single array or a dynamic list of arguments:

```
$input = $request->only(['username', 'password']);

$input = $request->only('username', 'password');

$input = $request->except(['credit_card']);

$input = $request->except('credit_card');
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is simple solution
Use array concept and its indexes

```php
$orders = $request->orders;
```

And use index to get value

```php
$val = $orders[0];
```

Or

```php
$val = $orders['return_url'];
```